# base_url Link Issue

Tags: php, navigation, base-url

I'm using following code:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.aaa.com/";
```

Also Im using Flash navigation:

```
on(release) {
getURL("http://www.aaa.com/xxx/index");
}
```

The Problem is When I give url as `http://aaa.com` in address bar Flash navigation link is not working. If i give link from `http://www.aaa.com` its work perfectly.

Can anyone solve my issue?

Or else, is it possible to use like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.aaa.com/";
$config['base_url'] = "http://aaa.com/";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite vague. But to redirect to `www` using `.htaccess` try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www|localhost
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the flash object trying to read a page / data from the server?
In this case, Cross-domain policy for flash prevents form accessing data which resides on other domains. (Sub domains, such ass www.aaa.com and aaa.com are treated as different domains.)
You would need to add a crosdomain.xml policy file http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Answer (score 0):

If Petah's answer doesn't help you, then it could very well be a setting with your web server. I use shared hosting and I know whenever I configure a new domain I have an option like this:

[image: Domain options on DreamHost]

If you own your own web server, check the httpd.conf file. Otherwise, if it's on shared hosting, see if there's a setting for making it required/non-required.